# SQLXMLBulkLoad: COMExecption was caught, error connecting to the data source

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net, bulk-load

I'm running into this error when trying to do a SQLXMLBulkLoad. Here's the configuration for the object:

```
Public Shared objbl As New SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.SQLXMLBulkLoad4
objbl.ConnectionString = ReadVariables("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=db1;Integrated Security=True")
objbl.ErrorLogFile = workingdirectory & "\error.log"
objbl.TempFilePath = workingdirectory
objbl.CheckConstraints = True
objbl.KeepIdentity = False
objbl.Transaction = True
objbl.FireTriggers = True
objbl.Execute(workingdirectory & "\xsdtempfile.xsd", fname)
```

Both the source and the destination are on locahost.

I'm failing to see what's wrong with my connection string.

The error happens on this line:

```
objbl.Execute(workingdirectory & "\xsdtempfile.xsd", fname)
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: @RomanPekar, in the title of this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
objbl.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;server=localhost;database=db1;integrated security=SSPI"
```

or try this

```
objbl.ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;server=localhost;database=db1;user id=User;password=Password;persist security info=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```